# Access Form1 from Form2 problem I need some help

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey guys I want to access form2 from form1 and I use this code..

MessageBox.Show(wb.name)   This line is working and I am getting browser name in messagebox but
         wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com"); this line not working

```
 Form1 frm = new Form1();
        foreach (Control item in frm.Controls)
        {
            if (item is WebBrowser)
            {
                WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)item;
                 MessageBox.Show(wb.name)
                 wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com"); 
                this.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Why must you loop through every single control in the form to find the `WebBrowser` rather than just use the `WebBrowser`'s name?

Comment: I used that too And same problem :(

Comment: Please describe "this line not working"

Comment: MessageBox.Show(wb.name) this code works  I can reach browser name but I have not navigated to google

wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com"); this code not works11

Comment: @ psygnosis :What is WebBrowser? Is you one of your Forms name?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look at what events are with the WebBrowser Object. Your call to this.Close() may be your undoing here. Try a Thread.Sleep(10000); before the this.Close() to see what your results are.

Answer (score 0):

The Navigate method does not wait for the WebBrowser to navigate to the specific page, but it returns immediately, and  it does the navigation asynchronously. The control has an event named DocumentCompleted, which is called when the web browser truly navigates to the specific page.

You should implement an event handler for the DocumentCompleted event, and write here what you want your program to do when it navigates to http://www.google.com